# row editing within a list

Tags: angular, datatable

i'm having trouble with editing a row within a list created by "ngFor".
The row consists of another list of complex component.
When i click on a row item i want to put it into editmode.

I can put it into edit mode by simply switch an flag and creating "editing components".
But the problem is that the creation takes long time.

To illustrate this i can provide these codes to you.

First approach: (Switch component into editing mode)

list.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="row of rows">
   <my-row [row]="row" (click)="putRowIntoEditMode"></my-row>
</div>
```

myrow.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="row.editMode">
    <ngFor="prop of row.properties>
        <edit-component [config]="prop.config" [data]="prop.data"></edit-component>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!row.editMode" <!-- normal mode -->
    <normal-component *ngFor="row of row.properties"></normal-component>
</div>
```

So every time i click on a row it should be put in edit mode. I have to set config and data for every edit-component in the list. Which takes extreme long because the list of properties can be very long. Normal component only display the value, while edit-component is more complex. It contains more logic in it.

So my another approach is to always having an "editing row", set the config to it once and move this row to the specified index within the the list and of course set it with new data properties of the selected row. But i don't know how to achieve it.

I hope you can help me.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are trying to achieve is that it no longer re-creates each row?

If so, add

```
<div *ngFor="row of rows; trackBy: rowFn">
  <my-row [row]="row" (click)="putRowIntoEditMode"></my-row>
</div>
```

and in your component

```
rowFn = index => index;
```

this is due to the use of trackBy in angular, it now tries only to update those elements that have to be re-rendered.. without the trackBy it has to re-render the full ngFor.

Hope this helps